# Slice a 3D array in to multiple 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape(64,64,3). How can we get three arrays of dimension (64,64) each.

Comment: `[arr[:,:,i] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Also I am looking for way to achieve this using vectorization and without using any for loop.

Comment: `x,y,z = np.moveaxis(arr, -1, 0)`

Comment: thanks Paul, this works. If you could write this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: For this small problem I found that `moveaxis` is actually slower.  But more important than speed is comprehensibility.  Do you understand the accepted answer?  Can you adapt it to other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `moveaxis` to move the to split axis all the way to the left and then use sequence unpacking:

```
x,y,z = np.moveaxis(arr, -1, 0)
```

Comment: The interface might not be quite so pretty, but `np.transpose` is faster (less overhead).

Comment: @hpaulj I never claimed otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is another case where iteration, for a few steps, is not bad.

```
In [145]: arr = np.ones((64,64,3))
```

Unpacking a list comprehension:

```
In [146]: a,b,c = [arr[:,:,i] for i in range(3)]
In [147]: a.shape
Out[147]: (64, 64)
```

Unpacking a transposed array:

```
In [148]: a,b,c = np.moveaxis(arr,-1,0)
In [149]: a.shape
Out[149]: (64, 64)
```

Timings for such a small example aren't ground breaking, but they hint at the relative advantages of the two approaches:

```
In [150]: timeit a,b,c = [arr[:,:,i] for i in range(3)]
3.02 µs ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [151]: timeit a,b,c = np.moveaxis(arr,-1,0)
18.4 µs ± 946 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The array unpacking (on the 1st dimension) requires converting the array into a list of 3 subarrays, as can be seen by these similar timings:

```
In [154]: timeit a,b,c = list(np.moveaxis(arr,-1,0))
17.8 µs ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [155]: timeit a,b,c = [i for i in np.moveaxis(arr,-1,0)]
17.9 µs ± 14.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It's not the unpacking or iteration that taking time.  It's the `moveaxis`:

```
In [156]: timeit np.moveaxis(arr,-1,0)
14 µs ± 4.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Looking at its code, we see that it uses `transpose`, after first constructing an `order` from the parameters:

Calling `transpose` directly is fast (since it just involves changing shape and strides):

```
In [157]: timeit arr.transpose(2,0,1)
688 ns ± 1.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And unpacking that transpose is a bit faster than my original list comprehension.

```
In [158]: timeit a,b,c = arr.transpose(2,0,1)
2.78 µs ± 9.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So `moveaxis` has a significant overhead relative to the rest of the task. That said, it probably does not increase with the side of the array.  It's a fixed overhead.

Comment: How about a generator expression instead of the list comprehension? Does that make a difference?