# How to split a 3D matrix into 3D matrices lined up in a list?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a NumPy array with the following shape:

```
(1532, 2036, 5)
```

I would like to generate a list of arrays where each one has the following shape:

```
(1532, 2036)
```

Comment: That would be 2D arrays I think. Simply use list comprehension - `[a[:,:,i] for i in range(a.shape[-1])]`?

Comment: Similar question (but with unpacking to variables): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101040/slice-a-3d-array-in-to-multiple-2d-arrays.  I proposed this list comprehension, the accepted answer transposed the axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) to signify all dimensions up to the last. For example:

```
arr = np.random.rand(4, 3, 2)
arr
array([[[ 0.35235813,  0.57984153],
        [ 0.53743048,  0.46753367],
        [ 0.80048303,  0.07982378]],

       [[ 0.1339381 ,  0.84586721],
        [ 0.81425027,  0.41086151],
        [ 0.34039991,  0.19972737]],

       [[ 0.2112466 ,  0.73086434],
        [ 0.03755819,  0.40113463],
        [ 0.74622891,  0.74695994]],

       [[ 0.99313615,  0.65634951],
        [ 0.90787642,  0.37387861],
        [ 0.8738962 ,  0.41747727]]])
```

The list of the last dimension arrays can be constructed as @Usernamenotfound mentioned or with `Ellipsis` like so:

```
[arr[..., i] for i in range(arr.shape[-1])]
[array([[ 0.35235813,  0.53743048,  0.80048303],
        [ 0.1339381 ,  0.81425027,  0.34039991],
        [ 0.2112466 ,  0.03755819,  0.74622891],
        [ 0.99313615,  0.90787642,  0.8738962 ]]),
 array([[ 0.57984153,  0.46753367,  0.07982378],
        [ 0.84586721,  0.41086151,  0.19972737],
        [ 0.73086434,  0.40113463,  0.74695994],
        [ 0.65634951,  0.37387861,  0.41747727]])]
```

Each element has the shape `(4, 3)`.

Likewise you could so the same for the first dimension, making 4 (3, 2) arrays.

```
[arr[i, ...] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
[array([[ 0.35235813,  0.57984153],
        [ 0.53743048,  0.46753367],
        [ 0.80048303,  0.07982378]]), array([[ 0.1339381 ,  0.84586721],
        [ 0.81425027,  0.41086151],
        [ 0.34039991,  0.19972737]]), array([[ 0.2112466 ,  0.73086434],
        [ 0.03755819,  0.40113463],
        [ 0.74622891,  0.74695994]]), array([[ 0.99313615,  0.65634951],
        [ 0.90787642,  0.37387861],
        [ 0.8738962 ,  0.41747727]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also permute the axes with [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) then simply iterate through the array:

```
import numpy as np
a = ... # Define the input array here
out = [a for a in np.transpose(arr, (2, 0, 1))]
```

Comment: To the downvoter... May I ask why you down voted? Would help me so I can improve on this post if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the 3D array using

```
[x[:,:,i] for i in range(5)]
```

The above would give you a list of 2D arrays.

The same process can be scaled for multidimensional arrays

Comment: You may want to make the loop adaptive to the number of slices in the array by examining the number of slices in the third dimension, or `for i in range(x.shape[2])`.